# Sharepoint O365 pnp js get all users

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, spfx-webparts, pnp

I know this has been asked several times but I haven't found a viable solution.

I am building a spfx webpart where I want to display every single user with name, title, email etc.

I am using the pnp-js library for this. When i try to access siteusers (as suggested in so many answers) i only get the ones that i have given permission.

I have given "Everyone" access to the site. I did try the following:

```
pnp.sp.web.siteUsers.get().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
});
```

But this only returns the groups and the users that i have added manual to the site.

How can I get info about every single user?

The search api is not an option because i would have to a make an HTTP call for each users to get username, email, title etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get all users using the REST API. When I've needed to do this I've instead used the Microsoft Graph.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

You will get a response back that looks something like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "6e7b768e-07e2-4810-8459-485f84f8f204",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "Conf Room Adams",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "Adams@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "Adams@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The documentation describing how to work with Users in the Microsoft Graph can be found here: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped that I shouldn't handle any authentication. Too bad they haven't integrated it more closely with Sharepoint Online. Seems like a pretty common requirement.